# How to read a CSV file with hindi character and display on html?

Tags: html, unicode

Html is display text like this. I already checked and meta charset is already `utf-8`. I don't know why is happening Please help :)

```
id,cityname,{{man1}},{{number1}},{{man2}},{{number2}},{{man3}},{{number3}},{{man4}},{{number4}}
78,à¤à¤¯à¤¾,vikasasash,1212121212,vikashas,N/A,vikassash,N/A,vikash,1212121212 77,à¤ªà¤à¤¨à¤¾,à¤ªà¤à¤¨à¤¾,1212121212,à¤ªà¤à¤¨à¤¾,9601860927,à¤ªà¤à¤¨à¤¾,1212121212,vikash,1212121212
89,à¤ à¤¾à¤£à¥,vikashas,1212121212,vikashas,N/A,vikash,1212121212,vikash,1212121212
87,à¤ªà¥à¤£à¥,vikashअयोध्या,N/A,vikash,N/A,vikash,N/A,vikash,N/A we are saved
```

I was reading the file like this and display it on the screen. Since meta is utf-8. it should display them correct but it is noot

```
      var readCSV = new FileReader();
      readCSV.readAsBinaryString(file);
      readCSV.onloadend = function () {

        //arrayofArray converting them into 2D 
        const arrayofArrays = convertCSVToArray(readCSV.result, {
          type: 'array',
          separator: ','
        });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors are you getting, what's happening? I see your data, but can you share the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Update question @rafaelcastrocouto

Comment: check for if hindi font needs to be added .

Comment: @AmolBais nope When I am reading from CSV then only it is not working otherwise Hindi character is showing correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example of how to parse the CSV with javascript.

I got no errors because of the hindi characters. Note that all values are strings and you still need to convert some values to numbers and handle the `{{man1}}` double brackets stuff.

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById("csv");

inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFile);

function handleFile () {
  let file = this.files[0];
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = handleText;
  fileReader.readAsText(file);
}

function handleText () {
  let lines = this.result.split('\n');
  let headers = lines[0].split(',');
  let parsed = [];
  for (let i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
    let line = lines[i].split(',');
    let item = {};
    for (let j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
      item[headers[j]] = line[j];
    }
    parsed.push(item);
  }
  console.log(parsed);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="csv" accept="text/csv">
```

Comment: it was very stupid of me to use `readAsBinaryString` instead of `readAsText`. Thanks :)